# Database error when inserting values into MySql

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have an error on insert value mysql.
Please see my PHP code

```
<?php
    $ali = $_POST['ali'];

    $con = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mohammad');

    if (!$con) {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }

    $insertinto_ic_add = "INSERT INTO sq (text) VALUES ('" . $ali . "')";
    mysqli_query($con, $insertinto_ic_add) or die("database error:" . mysqli_error($con));

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="ali">
</form>
```

I input the values " n't " and an error occurs:

> database error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 't')' at line 2

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Even [`real_escape_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2469308) cannot secure it completely. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: yes ' this code is exmple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: my friends, i have problem into mysql NO sql injection, please see my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that *this* is not showing SQL injection.  But the prevention for such is the same as the fix for your problem.  You *must* escape certain characters (in particular the apostrophe) in the text.

Notice that the error message even points to the apostrophe.

If you echoed the statement, you would see

```
INSERT INTO sq (text) 
VALUES ('blah blah don't do this')
```

Observe the *three* apostrophes, and think how confused the parser will be.

Better code would be something like

```
$mali = $con->real_escape_string($ali);
$insertinto_ic_add = "INSERT INTO sq (text) 
         VALUES ('" . $mali . "')";
```